# "Could not read the contents of media" - PERMISSION DENIED

Tags: permissions

How can I access all files and folders on my user  username/media/ directory?

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS.

Ubuntu's Nautilus can indeed access all files and folders in all locations. However, Ubuntu's software that I have downloaded (e.g. KRITA, WPS WRITER etc) can NOT access any file or folder on the /media directory.
Thanks in advance.